# Non-Wordpress domain on Bitnami WordPress multi-site

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf, bitnami

I've been fighting this issue for quite some time and perhaps don't have a good enough understand of Apache.

I have a Bitnami Wordpress Multi-site installation running on AWS lightsail.
I have 3 WP domains working fine.

I also have a 4th domain that I want to point to a custom non-Wordpress app using that same server.

A while back I asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638767/point-domain-to-directory-of-a-bitnami-wordpress-multi-site-instance/53705728#53705728

- Using this, I set up my app in a separate directory with a conf directory which I planned to include a vhosts file pointing my 4th domain name to the htdocs directory in this new location.
- The Bitnami Engineer that answered the question said to create an Alias, but unless I understand alias' incorrectly, they are only for directories. I can't use an alias for a separate domain (am I wrong?)

When I tried to add a VirtualHosts section, I received an error because I can't have both vhosts and httpd-prefix running on the same server I guess.

How can I leave httpd-prefix as-is for my wordpress multisite installation, but also point my 4th URL to the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I lost the comment in the other thread. If you follow the steps I mentioned in the other topic, you will have your custom application running at yourdomain/yourapp (yourapp is the name of the alias you configured).

In case you want to deploy that application using a custom virtual host, you will need to follow the steps I mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705728/4709625) but you will need to configure the following:

- Configure the ServerName and ServerAlias in the httpd-vhosts.conf file of your custom application.
- Include that httpd-vhosts.conf file inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf file. You can skip the step to include the httpd-prefix.conf file inside the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf one.
- Restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

To summarize: 
- You need to have your app's folder at /opt/bitnami/apps/yourapp. You will have 2 folders there, conf (Apache configuration files) and htdocs (files of the app)
- You will configure the virtual host in the httpd-vhosts.conf file and include the app's file inside the Apache's /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf file.

Comment: Thanks for your help again Jota! I think I am mostly there now. I have my site pointing to the appropriate directory. I am getting  a 403 error now for that specific site though even though everything in htdocs is set to 755.

Comment: Disregard the problem in my previous comment... It is working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too am attempting to do this.  I have a custom PHP script I need the server to execute and I can't for the love of god figure this out.  Unfortunately I don't have the bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf file.  Can someone please tell me what should be in this file and how it gets referenced for load since it doesn't exist?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/540657)